# iOS: UIView backgroundColor in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

So this problem is pretty weird and a little difficult to describe. Essentially I have a `UITableView` where each cell has an image, and a `UIView` covering part of the image. The `UIView` has it's background colour set to about 30% transparent white, giving it the appearance of washing out the image beneath. There's also some labels and such on it. All these views are added to a single parent container view, which is finally added to the cell's `contentView`. This all works fine - until I try to select the cell. For some reason, whenever the cell is highlighted, the `backgroundColor` property on each and every one of those views is set to clear, until the cell is unhighlighted (at which point the old colour returns).

Can anyone explain why this happens, and more important if there's a way to fix it? At most I could create a single pixel image of white, turn the `UIView` into a `UIImageView`, and set it's image to that pixel - but that's inelegant at best. Any suggestions?

Comment: please post some code of tableview didSelect and cellForRowAtIndexPath methods.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222736/uiview-backgroundcolor-disappears-when-uitableviewcell-is-selected for some options that may help.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417590/how-to-disable-highlight-subviews-message-for-uiview-uiviewcontroller-in-ios-s), replacing "_updateHighlightColorsForView" for "_setOpaque".

Comment: I'm not getting a clear picture about your problem, even then, try and set the background color of your UIView in the method [UITableViewDelegate willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:];

Answer (score 0):

When you select the cell, the implementation of `setSelected:animated:` is called and set the background color of all the views included in this cell to transparent.

Simply, you can just disable the selection of the cell by setting its `selectionStyle` to None:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Or, if you want to use the result of selection, you can override the `setSelected:animated:` method and reset the background color of your `UIView`